# What static caches exist for stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, offline

Stack overflow is currently overflown. Apart from google, what static caches (official or otherwise) exist for it?

Comment: Works fine right now for me.

Comment: Judging by the timestamps on the newest-questions page, it was down for about 19 minutes.

Comment: @Robert: they must have thought it's after work hours. But it's always Friday in Australia when it's Thursday midnight in Iceland!

Comment: Gosh darn that GMT+11

Answer (score 3):

Geez.  I hope the [new guy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-000004/) didn't reboot the servers by mistake.

BTW -- seems to be back up now.

Comment: LOL (LOL * fifteen)